# Fill formula right to end of row, without going to edge of worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

In Excel, suppose I have a row with, say, 26 formulas horizontally from `A1` to `Z1`, and then I move down to cell `A2` and type a formula. Now I want to fill that formula to the right, through cell `Z2`. The issue is that if I just use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, it will fill this formula to the edge of the worksheet. Normally I get around this by going to cell `A1`, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→ (right arrow)</kbd> to the end of the row (cell `Z1`), then drop down one row to cell `Z2`, put something (e.g., a `1`) into that field, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>← (left arrow)</kbd> to select cell `A2`, and then finally I do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, which will fill my formula only through cell `Z2`.

Is there a much easier way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

1) If your used range is between columns A and Z, then you can press Shift+Ctrl+End to select cells Ax:Zx (x being your current row). If you accidentally paste something outside of this range and delete it, then you can restore that range by saving the workbook.

2) You could put all of the formulas in Column A and then select all of the formulas and fill right in one action.

3) You can use this sequence (starting on a cell containing a newly entered formula):

- Ctrl+C
- Up
- Ctrl+Right
- Down
- Shift+Ctrl+Left
- Ctrl+V
- Down (you are now ready to enter a new formula)

(While this seems like a lot, it can catch on relatively quickly)

4) Record a macro to accomplish the same steps as 3 with relative references. Assign that to a simple keystroke such as Shift+Ctrl+A.

5) Write a macro that does the same as 4, but only takes 2 lines of code.

6) Continue using Ctrl+R to fill all the way to the end of the sheet. Once you have finished building out the worksheet, delete columns after Z.

Answer (score 0):

Its easier if you are working in rows you can just double click the little black box in the corner of a2 when it is selected.

For copying across columns I just

- navigate to Z2 from A1 (up, ctrl+right,down)
- select the range and copy (ctrl+shift+right, ctrl+right)

Fills the range, takes about a second, seems fast enough for me.